# Contagem de novas linhas em Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, newline

Desejo contar a quantidade de novas linhas de um arquivo. Para isso estou fazendo da seguinte maneira a leitura do arquivo :

```
const fs = require('fs')//utilizando o módulo fs

fs.readFileSync('<caminhoParaoPrograma>/programa.js')//leitura do arquivo desejado
```

A partir desta leitura do arquivo, necessito de uma lógica para que identique o caractere **'\n'** e faça a contagem do total destes no arquivo.
Como posso resolver isto?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), que testa uma string usando uma determinada expressão regular. No caso, usaremos a seguinte expressão:

```
/\n/g
```

Que irá buscar todas as quebras de linha contidas na string.

Algo assim:

```js
const text = `L
u
i
z`

const matches = text.match(/\n/g);

console.log(matches.length); // 3
```

Como você pode perceber acima, o `match` retorna um array contendo todas as strings que correspondem à expressão regular. Usamos a propriedade `length` para obter a quantidade de elementos encontrados.

Você ficará, então, com isto:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const contents = fs.readFileSync('<file-name>', 'utf8');
const matches = contents.match(/\n/g);

const count = matches.length; // Use `count` como precisar.
```

Comment: Obg pela resposta! Houve um pequeno erro nesta solução, ao utilizar 'const matches = contents.match(/\n/g)'. Foi retornado o seguinte erro : 'TypeError: contents.match is not a function'. O que pode ser feito para resolvê-lo? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: `contents` deve ser uma `string` para que o código funcione. Você deve se certificar que o seu arquivo está sendo tratado como string antes de fazer isso.